# UI Automation Mobile Safari on iOS Simulator

Tags: facebook, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, ui-automation, facebook-test-users

There is an [open bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/336433069797240/) regarding Facebook SSO to an iOS app with [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/), which it's status is fixed but it's not!

1. I've logged in into Facebook account, with a test user in my iOS
   Simulator - version 6.1, Xcode 4.6.2 through iOS **Simulator** >
   **Settings** > **Facebook**.
2. When I try to log in to an iOS app ,which I
   only test (have no source code), it throws me an error that I can't
   login using FB. (Won't reproduce with a regular FB account).
3. I gave up on the SSO, but now I have another problem, I need to click on
   'OK' button on mobile Safari automatically:

[image: Mobile Safari, iOS Simulator]

Any idea?